# Which software should i use to build webcam gesture control

Tags: webcam

I want to develop a software that uses the laptop's webcam to control various applications. Can you please help me out which softwares and programming languages will come in handy please

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have the most success with Java for this application in all honesty. Most webcam manipulation programs will use Java if they are not browser based flash apps. Java is installed on most personal computers and the community based support available is great.

Without knowing the applications you are wanting to interact with it is really had to give a solid unfortunately.